# Git files encryption to protect the source code from theft

Tags: encryption, git

I am using Git and have the following problem: In the company where I work you now want to protect the source code from theft. So if for some reason a developer lets the source code of a project go along and sells it, for example.

To prevent this, I thought about it for a long time and came to the conclusion that encrypting the source code is the best choice. 
Like [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) does, that's a very good idea.
Only with one mistake:
If I add a user's GPG key, he can decrypt all files, and the protection measure would be worthless.
The files of the developer should be decrypted locally and only remotely. (This way the developer does not always have to encrypt, push, decrypt the files.)

I tried to re-program [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) in Python (because of cross-platform) but then failed due to the Git attributes/smudge, clean filter drivers.

Do you know a possibility or an application that takes up exactly my problem?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3834/3).

Comment: If a developer has a locally decrypted repo, how is that protecting from theft? If it is not decrypted, how is he supposed to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Files Encryption for Business](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49568/git-files-encryption-for-business)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Keybase](https://keybase.io/) app. The feature includes built-in encrypted chat and signed git hosting. It is free, open source and available for macOS, iOS, Android, Linux, and Windows.

Run the app, then in **Git** tab you can add a new encrypted git repository (personal or team).

Comment: keybase Encrypts the whole repository.